# How do I finish deriving this property of normal subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Socratica has a fantastic [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYKdh5oQ4Zw) on normal subgroups and quotient groups, but there’s one part of which I can’t convince myself.

Let $G$ be a commutative group under juxtaposition, let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$, and let the quotient group $G/N$ be equipped with the operation $\cdot$ for clarity.  The members of $G/N$ are of the form $gN$, where $g\in G$, and the quotient group operation is defined by $$xN\cdot yN = zN \iff \forall g_1\in xN\ \ \forall g_2\in yN\ :\ g_1g_2\in zN$$

We know that the coset containing $g_1g_2=g_1g_2e$ is $g_1g_2N$ since $e\in N$. Therefore $\{g_1g_2N : g_1\in xN\wedge g_2\in yN\}\subseteq xN\cdot yN$.  However, the video claims $xyN = xN \cdot yN$.

How does one go from $\{g_1g_2N\}\subseteq xN\cdot yN$ to $xyN = xN \cdot yN$?  I tried to compare $G/N$ to $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$, but that didn’t make this step any clearer.

Comment: Because the commutativity of $G$ and the fact that $NN=N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$. $N$ being normal by definition means $gng^{-1} \in N$ for all $g \in G$ and for all $n \in N$.

This is equivalent to the statement $gNg^{-1} \subset N$ for all $g \in G$. And this is further equivalent to the statement $gNg^{-1} = N$ i.e. $gN = Ng$ for all $g \in G$.

Using this together with the fact that $N = NN$ (since $N$ is a subgroup), we have

$$(xN)(yN) = x(Ny)N = x(yN)N = xyNN = xyN.$$

A more direct way to see this is the following: Let $xN, yN \in G/N$ where $x, y \in G$. Then

$$ \begin{align} xN \cdot yN &= \{ xnyn : n \in N \} 
\\ & = \{ xy(y^{-1}ny)n: n \in N\} 
\\ & = \{ xy(y^{-1}n(y^{-1})^{-1})n: n \in N\} 
\\ &= \{ xyn'n: n,n' \in N\} 
\\ &= \{xy n'': n'' \in N \}
\\ &= xyN,
\end{align}$$

where in the second equality we used the fact that $e = yy^{-1}$ and in the fourth equality is where we used the normal property of $N$.

**Addendum:** Note that here, we don't even need $G$ to be commutative! Since it was given the fact that $G$ is a commutative group, we immediately have

$$xN \cdot yN = \{xnyn: n \in N \} = \{xynn: n \in N \} = xyN.$$